# Entity Framework, DbContext, SaveChanges() Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I'm having a strange issue with EF, DbContext and the SaveChanges() method. I am using EF 5, .NET 4.5 and a LocalDB. I am using Code First EF and have it create the Database automatically for me.

The problem is anything after the db.SaveChanges() call does not get called. Here is an example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var db = new DataLayer.DataContext())
        {
            Group g = new Group {
                Id = 0,
                Gid = "019282",
                Name = "Admin"
            };

            db.Groups.Add(g);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Testing");

    }
```

The MessageBox does not even show. Any idea what's going on? It's not throwing any errors so I can't even debug it.

**Edit:**

I found the following in the output. Maybe that's the reason. But why isn't an exception thrown?

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
```

**Edit:**

I think it's my fault and I didn't migrate when I removed a property from my Model.

Comment: Try to see InnerException.

Comment: Form1_Load does work if I place the MessageBox before the call to SaveChanges() it works.

Comment: What about InnerException?

Comment: Don't debug with MessageBoxes, put a breakpoint on SaveChanges.

Comment: Is this just a Table with no reference to another Table? How is the model laid out in the Database? And what is GId? Is that a Unique Identifier?

Comment: if you using auto-incremented primary key field then dont assign the value before the insertion.database automaticlly handle it.you cannot set value for autoincrement field

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Sql Profiler to see if any SQL is being executed against your LocalDB instance?

If it is an inconsistency in your model you could enable automatic migrations. There is also a flag you can set against your model indicating whether to allow data loss - AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed :

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Configuration>());
```

[Automatic migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What is the primary key of the table? If it's Id, then chances are it's an auto-increment field. Instead of setting it to zero, just leave it out and see if it works.

```
using (var db = new DataLayer.DataContext())
{
    Group g = new Group {
            Gid = "019282",
            Name = "Admin"
        };

        db.Groups.Add(g);
        db.SaveChanges();
}
```